# Using jQuery val() to send form data and using FormData to send for data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to send a file using an Ajax POST request using two methods:

**Method 1 (jQuery val())** -

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'somewhere',
    method: 'post',
    processData: true,
    contentType: true,

    data:{
      'data1': $('#fileinputid').val(),  // File input
}

success:function(){
    // Do something;
}

error:function(){
    // Do something;
},

});
```

**Method 2- (FormData)**

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-id"));

$.ajax({
    url: 'somewhere',
    method:'post',
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    contentType: false,

    data: formData,

    success: function(){
        // Do something for success
    },

    error: function(){
        // Do something for error
    },

});
```

Now, **Method 2** *worked*, but **Method 1** ***did not***. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Can you show your related `html` please?

Comment: `$('#fileinputid').val()` only gets you the file _name_, you simply can not upload a file with that. `FormData` is capable of creating the whole multipart/formdata request structure that is needed for a file upload.

Comment: @CBroe Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#fileinputid').val()` only gets you the file *name*. You can not upload a file with that.

`FormData` is capable of creating the whole multipart/formdata request structure that is needed for a file upload.

Answer (score 0):

`data1: formData` you have a typo here.

It should correctly be `data: formData`